# While recording a video using libgphoto2, can I get the last video frame for analysis?

Tags: linux, libgphoto2

Is it possible to get the last frame of a video being recorded by using the C libgphoto2 library ?

Is it also possible to achieve this result using the gphoto2 command line utility ?
If yes, what would be the commands ?

I want to get this frame periodically for image processing purposes (object detection), and consequently (depending on the image processing results), perform some actions (e.g.: stopping the video recording).

Thanks :)